# Cannot find class AnnotationSessionFactoryBean

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm getting:

```
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolve
```

I searched the internet and mostly found that people who had the same issue just didn't had the right jars in the right place.
If I look in my WEB-INF/lib folder in Tomcat I get the following listing:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   443432  3 mrt 16:48 antlr-2.7.6.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   445288 12 feb 18:47 antlr-2.7.7.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin     4467 12 feb 18:43 aopalliance-1.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin    43033  4 mrt 14:08 asm-3.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   278682  4 mrt 14:08 cglib-2.2.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   559366  4 mrt 14:08 commons-collections-3.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   575389 12 feb 18:47 commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin    60686  3 mrt 17:17 commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   313898 12 feb 18:47 dom4j-1.6.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   365546  4 mrt 13:59 hibernate-annotations-3.5.6-Final.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin    71283  4 mrt 13:59 hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin    81271  3 mrt 20:15 hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin  3123360  4 mrt 14:08 hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin  4317092  3 mrt 20:15 hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   426671  4 mrt 14:08 hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.10.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   476002  3 mrt 20:15 hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.0.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   102661  3 mrt 20:15 hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   633312  4 mrt 14:08 javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   648253  3 mrt 20:15 javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin    60539  3 mrt 20:15 jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin    11209  3 mrt 20:15 jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin    15071  4 mrt 14:08 jta-1.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin    23445  4 mrt 13:59 slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin    25496 12 feb 18:43 slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   331471  3 mrt 17:17 spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin    53081  3 mrt 17:16 spring-asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   589824  3 mrt 17:17 spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   831068  3 mrt 17:17 spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   107225  3 mrt 17:17 spring-context-support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   449324  3 mrt 17:17 spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   176311  3 mrt 17:17 spring-expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   544291  3 mrt 17:17 spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   573701  3 mrt 17:16 spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonas  admin   109318 12 feb 18:46 xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
```

So all the needed jars are there. So I can't see why I keep getting the classNotFound Exception.

Here's my hibernate.hbm.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop     key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>org.geiregat.jonas.entity</value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So all the needed jars are there

No, they're not.  `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` is in the `spring-orm` JAR, which you don't have.

Courtesy of [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=AnnotationSessionFactoryBean).

Comment: Thanks! I read in another post that spring-orm wasn't needed! Guess he was wrong!

Answer (score 1):

You need `spring-orm.jar`, as skaffman writes correctly. But you have way more problems than that. You have several libraries installed in multiple versions, which will at best confuse the classloader and at worse cause your application to work erroneously or not at all (especially when there are non-compatible changes between versions):

```
antlr-2.7.6.jar                               # delete this
antlr-2.7.7.jar  

commons-collections-3.1.jar                   # and this
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar

hibernate-annotations-3.5.6-Final.jar         # and this
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar # and this
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar # and this
hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.10.Final.jar      # and this
hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.0.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar

javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar                       # and this
javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar

slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar                           # and this
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
```